# Spring batch configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a problem with spring batch and spring boot

Here is my jobs.xml

```
<!-- stored job-meta in database -->
<bean id="jobRepository"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jobTransactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>


<bean id="dummyTask" class="ch.autexis.DummyTask"/>

<!-- define a job with multiple tasks/steps -->
<batch:job id="MESaaSConnectorJob" restartable="true">
    <batch:step id="job_1" allow-start-if-complete="true">
        <tasklet ref="dummyTask" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<!-- runner executes the job -->
<bean id="MESaaS_sensor_runner" class="ch.autexis.RunScheduler">
    <property name="job" ref="MESaaSConnectorJob" />
    <property name="launcher" ref="jobLauncher" />
</bean>
```

Here is my Runscheduler:

```
@Component
public class RunScheduler {

private JobLauncher launcher;
private Job job;

public void run() {

    try {

        String dateParam = new Date().toString();
        JobParameters param =
                new JobParametersBuilder().addString("date", dateParam).toJobParameters();

        System.out.println(dateParam);

        JobExecution execution = launcher.run(job, param);
        long duration = execution.getEndTime().getTime() - execution.getStartTime().getTime();
        System.out.println("Job:" + job.getName() + " ended with status " + execution.getStatus().toString()
                + " and duration of " + duration + "ms");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public JobLauncher getLauncher() {
    return launcher;
}

public void setLauncher(JobLauncher launcher) {
    this.launcher = launcher;
}

public Job getJob() {
    return job;
}

public void setJob(Job job) {
    this.job = job;
}
 }
```

Here is the DummyTask:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;

public class DummyTask implements Tasklet {

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Dummy - Task executed");
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}

}
```

And here is my stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobOperator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.ListableJobLocator]: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.ListableJobLocator] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.ListableJobLocator] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at ch.autexis.BatchApplication.main(BatchApplication.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.ListableJobLocator] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Do you have any idea why the jobOperator bean can not be created?

Thanks for help

Comment: I think you are trying to autowire a bean in `ch.autexis.RunScheduler` which is not there in spring context .attach that `ch.autexis.RunScheduler ` class in your post for more information and if u have autowired `@Autowired
 @Qualifier("jobOperator")
 private Job job;` Your giving a wrong name in bean qualifier.Use `MESaaSConnectorJob` in place of `jobOperator`

Comment: I added the RunScheduler to my question

Answer (score 2):

Use the following annotation on your Application class to read the xml config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("applicationContext.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring can find job in its context.You have to use **bean id** as **qualifier** and inject it into your Class. You have to autowire your Job like

```
  @Autowired 
    @Qualifier("MESaaSConnectorJob") 
    private Job job;
```

For `jobLauncher` it will take by default spring bean name convention.For example `JobLauncher` to `jobLauncher`.You don't need any `@Qualifier` for that.

Comment: It's still the same error when I autowire the job.

The error comes from the "jobOperator" UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Comment: post that `DummyTask` class also may be some dependencies are missing in that.

Comment: where is `jobTransactionManager` bean in your xml use this `<bean id="jobTransactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />`.You have problem in `jobRepository` also it is not configured properly.You can check constructors available for that class depends on your spring batch version.